# Authorisation Policy in Identity 3 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have done a lot of research but am still not sure if I am doing this correctly.
The best resource I found was here

http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/

Given an ApplicationUser class extended to include a list of Authorized account numbers I want to restrict the user to only view statements (and other actions based) on their authorized accounts). I would think this is a very common design however most of the articles on the net refer to previous versions of identity.

(PS I am injecting UserManager in the Controller constructor)

Here is my action

```
public IActionResult GetStatement(int accountNo,DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate)
{
    var user = userManager.Users
        .Include(u => u.AuthorisedAccounts)
        .Where(u => u.Id == User.GetUserId())
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (user.AuthorisedAccounts != null)
    {
        foreach (var account in user.AuthorisedAccounts)
        {
            if (account.AccountNo == accountNo)
                return View(statementService.GetStatement(accountNo, startDate, endDate, 0));
        }
    }
    return HttpUnauthorized();
}
```

I cant help feeling there is a better way?
 Basically I want to authorize based on the action parameter."accountNo"

Any hints on what approach to take.

Comment: One thing to note - authorization is not part of identity. It's entirely separate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you'd use resource based, with the account being the resource. The documentation for this is at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html

To start with you'd define an operation of Read,

```
public static class Operations
{
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Read =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement   { Name = "Read" };
}
```

Now you'd have a policy for AccountAccess

```
public class AccountAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<
    OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Account>
{
    IUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountAuthorizationHandler(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context,
                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
                                   Account resource)
    {
        // Pull the user ID claim out from the context.User
        var userId = context.User.....
        // Get the current user's account numbers.       
        var user = userManager.Users
            .Include(u => u.AuthorisedAccounts)
            .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // Now check if the user's account numbers match the resource accountNumber, and 
    // also check the operation type, in case you want to vary based on create, view etc.
    if (user.AuthorisedAccounts.Contains(resource.AccountId &&
        requirement.Name == "View")
   {
      context.Succeed(requirement);
   } 
}
```

After that register your policy in the DI container, within configure services;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization();

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,
                          AccountAuthorizationHandler>();
}
```

In your controller you inject the AuthorizationService;

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public AccountController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
}
```

Then, within your controller, after you've loaded the account resource you'd do something like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> View(int accountId)
{
    Account account = accountManager.Find(accountId);

    if (account == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    if (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, account, Operations.Read))
    {
        return View(account);
    }
    else
    {
        return new ChallengeResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK Implementing this today.  I am fairly new to DI but in this case I have problem with the `services.AddInstance<IAuthorizationHandler>(
        new Authorization.AccountAuthorizationHandler());`  it seems I cant instantiate it without passing usermanager.  But I thought the Authorization Handler sorted its own DI?

Comment: Is Singleton safe with UserManager as it uses DbContext?

Comment: OK Im still getting stuck - IAuthorizationHandler only contains Handle no AuthorizeAsync.

Comment: I've sent an email about user manager. Why are you expecting the handler to have Authorize async? You are injecting the AuthorizationService into your controllers - see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html

Comment: Ah yes I was trying to inject the handler not the IAuthorisationService into the controller sorry.  I have read the docs several times just  passed me by I guess.

Comment: didn't get the email BTW.  Still curious about user manager in a singleton as AFAIK it uses DbContext and everything I read says don't share DBContext in a singleton.

Comment: I meant I've sent some mail internally. I'm on vacation for two weeks now.

Comment: But in all honesty I think you have your pieces backwards. The account would have owners, and you'd inject your account repository and query it to see if the current user is allowed.

Comment: Yes I had thought about it that way as well  Its a many to many relationship so AuthorisedAccounts is the join table  I suppose I could rename the table AccountOwners but it amounts to the same thing.  That still going to involve DBContext in a singleton though?

Comment: But in that case you're loading the account resource inside the controller then passing it down in the authorise call rather than injecting it into the handler. So no singleton concerns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98620/discussion-between-mikes-so-and-blowdart).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to define your authorization policy in a way that lets you use it for an `[Authorize]` attribute, you could alter the approach seen [in this article](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/):

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // inline policies
    options.AddPolicy("AccessByAccountNumber", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireDelegate((context, requirement) =>
        {
            var httpContext = (context as dynamic).HttpContext;

            // Proceed to grab the account number from the request values
            // and compare it against the user object stored in 'context.User'
        });
    });
});
```

The downside of this is that you would need to ensure that all of the actions where you use the attribute do so in a consistent way, i.e. using the same name for the action parameter or route parameter every time.

@blowdart's example of using the `IAuthorizationService` in the controller action demonstrates a way of using and re-using a policy which allows for the parameter names to be decoupled from the policy itself. Though we can see that the `IAuthorizationService` does not offer a strongly-typed generic method, it would seem to offer a less brittle approach to implementing resource-based policies.

Comment: This looks interesting would the Attribute look like [Authorize("AccessByAccountNumber")] Thanks a lot BTW

Comment: The problem with parsing the request values is generally they're not that useful. The resource itself would hold the information for the decision, for example a document has an author field, which is why we don't recommend that route. It's workable in this case because the user object holds a list of account numbers, rather than the account holding a list of authorized users which is more typical.

Comment: Good point.,once you move away from the simplest case the request may not have everything you need to make the desision.  Hadn't thought about that.